# Does Hackage remove files from uploaded package tarfiles?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I [got an issue report recently that my package's HSpec file was missing from the hackage tarfile](https://github.com/rampion/ReadArgs/issues/4), which seemed rather odd to me.

I checked it out though, and the user was right:

```
% curl -O http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ReadArgs/1.2/ReadArgs-1.2.tar.gz 
% tar tzf ReadArgs-1.2.tar.gz
ReadArgs-1.2/
ReadArgs-1.2/LICENSE
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgs.cabal
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgs.hs
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgsEx.hs
ReadArgs-1.2/Setup.hs
```

However, running through all the commits in my git repos, it seems like `cabal sdist` would always include `ReadArgsSpec.hs` in the package.

```
% cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring ReadArgs-1.2...
% cabal sdist
Building source dist for ReadArgs-1.2...
Preprocessing library ReadArgs-1.2...
Preprocessing executable 'ReadArgsEx' for ReadArgs-1.2...
Source tarball created: dist/ReadArgs-1.2.tar.gz
% tar tzf dist/ReadArgs-1.2.tar.gz
ReadArgs-1.2/
ReadArgs-1.2/LICENSE
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgs.cabal
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgs.hs
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgsEx.hs
ReadArgs-1.2/ReadArgsSpec.hs
ReadArgs-1.2/Setup.hs
```

So now, I can think of three possibilities:

1. I generated the tarfile I uploaded to hackage using something other than `cabal sdist`, and that process left out `ReadArgsSpec.hs`.
2. I altered my `ReadArgs.cabal` file before I ran `cabal sdist` in such a way as to exclude `ReadArgsSpec.hs` but failed to commit my change.
3. Hackage removed `ReadArgsSpec.hs` from the package file.

I view (1) and (2) as possible, but unlikely, especially since the earlier two versions of my package seem to have the same issue, and I can't think that I'd performed the same odd behavior each time.

Which leaves me with (3), which only seems likely in contrast.  Is Hackage removing `ReadArgsSpec.hs` from my uploaded tarfile? If so, how should I alter [my `ReadArgs.cabal` file](https://github.com/rampion/ReadArgs/blob/master/ReadArgs.cabal) to make sure it is included?

Comment: I would be surprised by (3). Can you check, `cabal sdist`, verify that `ReadArgsSpec.hs` is in the tarball, and upload?

Comment: Daniel Fischer: right you are.  Well, that was odd.